# Table creation failing when column is array type in Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have Syntax error in SQL statement while creating table when using `list-array` types.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table vehicle (id  serial not null, vehicle_types varchar[[*]] primary key (id))"; expected "(, FOR, UNSIGNED, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
create table vehicle (id  serial not null,  vehicle_types varchar[], primary key (id)) [42001-199]
```

My table definition looks like this.

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "created"})
@Getter
@Setter
@TypeDef(
        name = "list-array",
        typeClass = ListArrayType.class
)
public class Vehicle {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @JsonIgnore
   private Integer id;

   @Type(type = "list-array")
   @Column(
        name = "vehicle_types",
        columnDefinition = "varchar[]"
   )
   private List<String> vehicleTypes;

}
```

And I have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?.

Comment: You are using H2 database? They do not have typed arrays https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type

Comment: Is there something I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed.

Changed `columnDefinition` to `array` from `varchar[]`

```
@Type(type = "list-array")
@Column(
   name = "vehicle_types",
   columnDefinition = "array"
)
private List<String> vehicleTypes;
```